# JavaFX editable ComboBox in a table view

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am using a editable ComboBox cell in a table view. Here is my ComboBox cell class

```
public class ComboBoxCell extends TableCell<ClassesProperty, String> {

    private ComboBox<String> comboBox;

    public ComboBoxCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();

        if (comboBox == null) {
            createComboBox();
        }

        setGraphic(comboBox);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);


        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            comboBox.requestFocus();
            comboBox.getEditor().requestFocus();
            comboBox.getEditor().selectAll();


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (comboBox != null) {
                    comboBox.setValue(getString());
                }
                setGraphic(comboBox);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createComboBox() {
        // ClassesController.getLevelChoice() is the observable list of String
        comboBox = new ComboBox<>(ClassesController.getLevelChoice());
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()*2);
        comboBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit(comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

The problem I need to press three clicks on the table cell to get the text field of the combo box to edit the contents. Is there a way to make it in two clicks? I even used Platforn runlater but when I try to edit a cell at first time it takes three mouse clicks but at the second time only two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

In your overridden cell.startEdit() method, Add a ListView with a textfield, then add this listview to setGraphic. This will show the listview directly once the row is selected and the cell is clicked, the listview will be inside the tablecell, I am yet to find a way to make it as a popup