# Javafx : ComboBoxTableCell - how to select a value in one click?

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview, mouseevent

I have a TableView with a ComboBoxTableCell, when using the default implementation the user have to click **three** times to select a value from of the ComboBox's list.
I want when the user clicks on the cell to show the combo box list. I based my solution on this one: 
[JavaFX editable ComboBox in a table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988027/javafx-editable-combobox-in-a-table-view)

The cell does get into edit mode (startEdit() is called) but it takes another click to show the list of values, what am I missing?

```
table.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> 
{
 if (table.getEditingCell() == null) 
 {
     TablePosition focusedCellPos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
     table.edit(focusedCellPos.getRow(), focusedCellPos.getTableColumn());
 }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: By default it takes a double click to get into editing mode and a single click to expand the `ComboBox`. You reduced this to a single click for getting into editing mode but you cannot you cannot open the combobox's listview without another click (except perhaps for a really ugly css "hack"). I'd recommend using a custom `TableCell` implementation. Personally I'd prefer to keep the combobox always active instead, since showing a combobox and opening the drop down would be behavior that I don't expect from a table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem - bubbling up again after quite a while :)

Looks like the approach of the OP is indeed working (as of fx11, some bugs around its editing seem to be fixed) - with a little help from the combo cell:

- start editing in a single click handler on the tableView (from OP)
- extend ComboBoxTableCell and override its startEdit to open the dropDown

Code snippet:

```
// set editable to see the combo
table.setEditable(true);
// keep approach by OP
table.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
    TablePosition<Person, ?> focusedCellPos = table.getFocusModel()
            .getFocusedCell();
    if (table.getEditingCell() == null) {
        table.edit(focusedCellPos.getRow(),
                focusedCellPos.getTableColumn());
    }
});
// use modified standard combo cell shows its popup on startEdit
firstName.setCellFactory(cb -> new ComboBoxTableCell<>(firstNames) {

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        if (isEditing() && getGraphic() instanceof ComboBox) {
            // needs focus for proper working of esc/enter 
            getGraphic().requestFocus();
            ((ComboBox<?>) getGraphic()).show();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the cleanest solution to this problem, but I found a workaround to make the ComboBoxTableCells drop down its menu in just 1 click:

```
column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Person, String> call(TableColumn<Person, String> column) {
          ComboBoxTableCell cbtCell = new ComboBoxTableCell<>(cbValues);
          cbtCell.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
              // Without a Person object, a combobox shouldn't open in that row
              if (((Person)((TableRow)cbtCell.getParent()).getItem()) != null) {
                Robot r = new Robot();
                r.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
                r.mouseClick(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
              }
            }
          });
          return cbtCell;
        }
      });
```

PS: I know that this topic is a bit old, but I also stumbled upon this problem recently and could not find any working solution to it online. As I sad, it's not the cleanest workaround, but at least it does its job. ;)

Comment: wicked approach, creating a Robot on enter - but then, if it's working :) Wondering whether [showing the popup in the cell's startEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57556418/203657) might work in your context as well